# PHP Warning in Filemtime() & Cannot modify Header information - Headers Already Sent Error

Tags: php, debugging, header

With help of @James, the image generator is in fine condition. Now, there is a tiny but strange error that the image engine outputs when a file or folder is **non existent**. Indeed there should be **an** error but i'm unsure wether it sould be this one below. Here is what happens when google tries to fetch an old non existent folder/image.jpg via the imgcpu.php thumbnail generator:

```
[20:24:25] PHP Warning: filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]: stat failed for old_folder/old-image.jpg in imgcpu.php on line 802
[20:24:25] PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at imgcpu.php:802) in imgcpu.php on line 201

[20:26:31] PHP Warning: filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]: stat failed for old_folder/old-image.jpg in imgcpu.php on line 802
[20:26:31] PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at imgcpu.php:802) in imgcpu.php on line 201

[20:28:24] PHP Warning: filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]: stat failed for old_folder/old-image.jpg in imgcpu.php on line 802
[20:28:24] PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at imgcpu.php:802) in imgcpu.php on line 201

[20:31:03] PHP Warning: filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]: stat failed for old_folder/old-image.jpg in imgcpu.php on line 802
[20:31:03] PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at imgcpu.php:802) in imgcpu.php on line 201
```

It seems that line 201 and 802 have something to do with it:

```
line 201**     header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
line 202       die($message);
....
line 801       header("Content-type: " . $this->_mime);
line 802**     $last_modified = filemtime($source);
```

**Question: Is the error correct?** or should the warning be solved somehow? If so, how?

Comment: the error message from filemtime is output which breaks headers, so fix the filemtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to get the last modification date of a file if that file doesn't exist, I suppose.

You should check whether the file exists, first, using the [**`file_exists()`**](https://www.php.net/file_exists) function.

I suppose you should use something like this :

```
if (file_exists($source)) {
    $last_modified = filemtime($source);
    // Use the $last_modified variable
}
else {
    // the file doesn't exist => 404
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    die;
}
```

Comment: thanks. That sounds logical. How do I do that? What elements go in the () and {}?  `if file_exists(??????){??????}`

Comment: I've edited my answer with some idea of code ; hope this helps :-)